# GIMP: Setting entire foreground to a particular colour

Tags: gimp

In GIMP version 2.8, I have an image with a black foreground, and a transparent background. I want to set the entire foreground to red, instead of black. What's the simplest way of doing this?

I have tried using the fuzzy select tool and doing a bucket fill on the selection, but this doesn't seem to select the entire foreground. After the bucket fill, there is still a black line around the edge of the foreground image. So it seems that the fuzzy selector didn't select the entire foreground. On closer inspection, the edges of the foreground are not perfectly black, but have some grey pixels. But when using the fuzzy selection, I set a very high threshold (250), so I would have thought this this would select the entire foreground, including the grey pixels.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The gray pixels aren't grey, they are partially transparent black pixels. If you replace black, you want to keep that partial transparency because this is what gives smooth edges. And there is an easy solution:

- Set the alpha-lock of the layer (this is the checkerboard icon at the top of the Layers list) (or in code: gimp-layer-set-lock-alpha)
- **Do not use selection**.
- Bucket-fill the layer with the required color. The alpha-lock will preserve the opacity of the pixels.